# Array Modifier - Equal space between all duplicates (Loops)

Tags: modifiers

I know this has been asked already, but the answers, despite giving a certain degree of improvement give no satisfying solution for those who want extreme accuracy.

When using the array modifier for a loop/circuit as the path, is there any way to have ALL spaces (Including the one between first and last duplicate) to be the same distance apart, so that there isn't the typical inaccurately spaced gap/distance that occurs between the first and last duplicate?

For example if I was using a plain circle as a path, couldn't I click a theoretical option for example, lets call it "Consistent Spacing" that would divide into equally spaced sections as I increase the duplicate count, so if I have 3 pieces the path would be divided into 3 and the duplicates placed appropriately?

The only reason this matters so much is because of some very irregular paths that I need to have spaced accurately. One easier example would be accurately spaced tank tracks.

Perhaps there is an easier way, or I'm underestimating/getting something wrong. If manual math is the only solution, are there any direct resources for this?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please increase clarity by including screen snapshots with annotations if necessary.  This will help others to understand your extreme accuracy problem.  Please show what is successful/desired and what has failed.

Comment: Please show train tracks.  Please show irregular tracks.

Answer (score 2):

- Consider an [Array Modifier] followed by a [Curve modifier]

[image]

- In the above image you see some distortion of angles between faces.
- Consider a script which calculates [x constant offset] of the array modifier.  Note the warning.
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
- Consider a [spline constraint ] where each track has a one-to-one correspondence with a single bone.

Comment: Added picture that hopefully makes it a little clearer, the same spacing principle would be present for anything that needed to be duplicated, such as traintracks.