# Duplicating At Regular Intervals Along Mesh Face

Tags: mesh

I am hoping someone can give me a bit of advice on how to achieve something.

I am currently working on a model for one of the old MK .. British tanks.
In the picture below you can see i have a lot of the basic elements, and am looking to attach the squarish object to the tracks at regular intervals.

I know i can snap objects together, in this case to the face of the mesh making up the track, and can duplicate the object and repeat that process to make the spacing the same. But i am not sure how i can achieve snapping all of the duplicate objects to the track as the track of course goes around the entire tank as opposed to being just a straight line.

Obviously i am a self taught amateur, so i am sorry if this seems like a stupid question, or if i am simply doing this is a difficult or stupid way.
I make 3D models for my own love of doing so, and so am not exactly the most knowledgeable.

Any help or pointers would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6486/duplicate-along-path-with-uniform-spacing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curvehttps://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31744/array-modifier-equal-space-between-all-duplicates-loops https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38560/stretching-problems-with-curve-modifier https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34932/skinning-a-simple-tank-track-for-unity3d

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+tracks https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68923/torus-object-stretched-in-array-curve-modifier/68925?r=SearchResults&s=1|61.3602#68925